How to draw a line with a short piece at beginning or end cut off
In maplibre, is there any way to draw a line that's shorter than its actual length in pixel unit, just like CIMGeometricEffectCut in ArcGIS Maps SDK for js.
The ideal result is shown in the next picture 
Any way to get the effect is OK and any reply would be greatly appreciated!
